# How to resolve issues when deserializing json with regular expression tokens in it

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize json that contains a regular expression string and I'm running into an issue where JsonConvert is treating \w as a control character instead of a literal and then complaining that it can't parse it. How would I specify as part of the converter options to ignore control sequences and treat it as a literal? I'm parsing the json into a dictionary where the regex is going to be a value.

Current deserialization code.

```
typeSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(typeJson) ?? new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

I've tried making a call with a RegexConverter like so but that doesn't resolve the issue either.

```
typeSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(typeJson,new JsonConverter[]{new RegexConverter()}) ?? new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

What I could do I guess is to override the RegexConverter and write my own that sees the \w or any other regex control characters and returns them as literal strings but I wonder if there's any other simpler, idiomatic way to do what I want here?

Comment: Show the data you are trying to deserialize. Chances are it was serialized wrong (it should have been serialized `\\w`, not `\w`)

Comment: I'm saving the json without escaping it. {Pattern:"\b[M]\w+"}. In the database field where it's saved to it's like that, but on retrieval into an entity string prior to deserialization it escapes the \b. {Pattern:"\\b[M]\w+"}

Comment: put it in your database so it looks like this `{Pattern:"\\b[M]\\w+"}` Then when you deserialize it, it will be a string that contains `\b[M]\w+`.

Comment: `{Pattern:"\b[M]\w+"}` is malformed.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error.  And even if I fix the quoting for the property name, to be `{"Pattern":"\b[M]\w+"}`, the string value has invalid escaping.  As shown at https://www.json.org/json-en.html, the backquote character is used to escape subsequent characters, so if you want to include a backquote in the string value, it must be itself escaped - as mentioned by @Andy.  My recommendation is not to try to manually create your JSON, instead use a JSON serializer.  That way you will avoid this sort of problem.

Comment: That works. But this is a user input field. How would you tell the difference if a user wanted to add an escape sequence or a regex token if it is escaped?

Comment: let the serializer/deserializer do the work. you shouldn't have to worry about any of it.

Comment: Oh to your point, @dbc, the json is malformed in the keys not being quoted but that's intentional as a means to save room in the string. I can get it working when I let JsonConvert serialize it but how would I prevent it from putting quotes around the keys?

Comment: You wouldn't. Asking a JSON serializer to please violate the spec and produce something that's actually not JSON because you want to save room is, well, ill-advised. If you want to save room, compress the output, this saves far more than quotes around keys. If space is at a premium and simple compression won't cut it for whatever reason, there are binary serialization schemes like BSON and Protobuf. But don't reach for those if it's just premature optimization, like omitting quotes around keys is.